# SharePoint List Version History -Restore full list or multiple items

Tags: list, restore, version

is there a way to restore a prior version of a sharepoint list? I have versioning switched on and able to restore items individually, but I am looking to restore hundreds of records. Is there a way to revert to a prior list, just like how you can restore a prior file, as of the last backed up version??
Or is there a way to restore multiple items at a time? I can’t seem to find an answer through googling. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Using the version history of a list, you can only see the changes done on a particular item during its lifetime.

There is no option to restore the entire list or a particular item using the version history

What you can do is, using a power automate or console application you can get the version history of a particular item using Rest API and update the same item using the Rest API or Update item in power automate.

Using this logic you can restore the entire list.

[https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items(1)/versions?$select=Title,VersionLabel](https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle(%27mylist%27)/items(1)/versions?$select=Title,VersionLabel)

Comment: Thank you for the response and suggestion! I will definitely make note of this for next time. I had to try to restore everything before users noticed the incorrect data, so I did it the ugly way. I literally went into each and every record to revert each item back to the prior one in the version history. There were 700 records! I kept thinking there’s gotta be a better way..  but I couldn’t find anything through my research..